# Getting existing app with fingerprint authentication to work with iPhone X FaceId

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x, touch-id, face-id

I have an app already developed and is live on the store. Its working well and has fingerprint authentication implemented. Now that Apple has made it mandatory to provide iPhone X support, I will be releasing one more update of the app.

But, i wish to understand what will happen if install the already submitted version of the app on iPhone X..?

I have read that -

1. App will provide a compatibility alert saying `This app was designed to use Touch ID and may not fully support FaceID`, But it goes away if we insert a key `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` in the plist.
2. I have also read that the app will crash if build using iOS 11 SDk (without the key `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` in the plist).

**Here is my question** - what if the app is build using iOS 8 and installed in iOS 11, will it still crash ? if not, how will be the exact behaviour..? I have tested in the simulator and the app did not crash but i do not have iPhone X available at hands and cannot crosscheck the same on the actual device.

**NOTE** - This crash is observed on the device more and not on simulator.

3. How important it is to have the word `FaceId` in the app running on iPhone X. What if I use a general terms like "Biometric authentication" in place of touchId & FaceId. Will the app still be fine and won't end up rejected ?

Any help or leads will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in that you need the `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` key in your plist to properly support Face ID.

If you built the app using Xcode 9 against the iOS 11 SDK, even if you set the target to iOS 8, you need to include that key to support iPhone X.

That said, I don't see how this might be crashing. The same code that you use for Touch ID also supports Face ID.

Comment: @Shailesh I don't know 100%, but I would say you could get by with "Biometric Authentication".

Answer (score 0):

I use this to handle faceID or touchID

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
                if (myContext.biometryType == LABiometryTypeTouchID) {
                    SwitchItem *touchIdItem = [[SwitchItem alloc] init];
                    touchIdItem.name = NSLocalizedString(@"PROFILE_SETTINGS_TOUCHID", nil);
                    touchIdItem.active = [[[Global instance] objectInKey:KEY_TOUCHID_ENABLED] boolValue];
                    [self.dataSource addObject:touchIdItem];
                } else if (myContext.biometryType == LABiometryTypeFaceID) {
                    SwitchItem *faceIdItem = [[SwitchItem alloc] init];
                    faceIdItem.name = NSLocalizedString(@"PROFILE_SETTINGS_FACEID", nil);
                    faceIdItem.active = [[[Global instance] objectInKey:KEY_FACEID_ENABLED] boolValue];
                    [self.dataSource addObject:faceIdItem];
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
                SwitchItem *touchIdItem = [[SwitchItem alloc] init];
                touchIdItem.name = NSLocalizedString(@"PROFILE_SETTINGS_TOUCHID", nil);
                touchIdItem.active = [[[Global instance] objectInKey:KEY_TOUCHID_ENABLED] boolValue];
                [self.dataSource addObject:touchIdItem];
            }
        }
```

You have to evaluate iOS version and after that yo can suppose if the gadget have a touchID or faceID